# Consuming SOAP webservice using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, complextype

I'm having problem with a call to a Web Service using PHP.

The provider of the service gives an example to use it with parameters :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parameters>
    <START_DATUM>2010-07-20</START_DATUM>
    <ENDE_DATUM>2010-07-20</ENDE_DATUM>
    <GRUPPE_ID>231</GRUPPE_ID>
</Parameters>
```

This is the code I use to perform the call (which return nothing):

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$params = "<Parameters><START_DATUM>2015-03-31</START_DATUM><ENDE_DATUM>2015-03-31</ENDE_DATUM><GRUPPE_ID>231</GRUPPE_ID></Parameters>"
$result=$client->GetXMLResultOf("SIEMS_Planung", $params);
var_dump($result);
```

The problem is the format of the parameters.

Here is the XMLSchema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Parameters">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="START_DATUM" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="ENDE_DATUM" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="GRUPPE_ID" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I format the parameters to make this work ?
I tried many code that I found on the Internet but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 :

The GetXMLResultOf method is the method from the Web Service.
The signature is : GetXMLResultOf(Profil-Name, Parameter)

Answer :

I found the problem ... the < Parameters> was not needed in my string $params.
It is weird because with an another profil he's needed.

Thanks for the reply and the time you spent to answer to me.

Comment: What SoapClient are you using? The one that comes with PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) or another one?

Comment: I'm using the one that comes with PHP yes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the GetXMLResultOf method for the class SoapClient :
http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapclient.php

But, this is an example of a classic Soap call :

```
try {

  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
  $params = array('START_DATUM' => '2015-03-31',
                  'ENDE_DATUM' => '2015-03-31',
                  'GRUPPE_ID' => '231');

  $response = $client->__soapCall($method, array($params));
  return $response->return;

}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
  error_log($e->detail);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but there is still a problem.
<ERRORS>Parameter 'RECEIVETEXT' not foundGetXMLResultOf / xmlResult__CompleteQuery
</ERRORS>

Comment: This is curious ... The XMLSchema does not specify the RECEIVETEXT parameter